# How to calculate running sum based on ID and date

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset in which I have the following columns: date, id, value. I then want a running sum of the preceding 3 days (including the current day itself) for every id.

I have tried to look at several similar questions at StackOverflow, but none of them gives me the right result.

If the id has been seen only once within the last 3 days, the sum should be equal to that single value. The same goes if it has been seen two times within the last 3 days, obviously.

The desired output is the column "sum_3days":

```
date    id  value   sum_3days  
01/01/2019  1   2   2    
01/01/2019  2   3   3    
02/01/2019  1   2   4    
02/01/2019  2   5   8   
03/01/2019  1   2   6   
03/01/2019  2   1   9    
04/01/2019  1   6   10    
05/01/2019  1   3   11
06/01/2019  1   6   15
06/01/2019  2   8   8
07/01/2019  1   3   12    
07/01/2019  2   2   10
```

So basically, the sum should "give me the sum of all the values every id has had within the last 3 days"

Comment: You're probably looking for the `cumsum()` method: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html

Comment: @DroidX86 looks more likely to be `groupby` and `rolling` and `cumsum`...

Comment: I think your calculation of `sum_3days` is wrong?  eg, `06/01/2019  2` should be `14`, not `8`..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) and a `lambda` with [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html) and [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.3/generated/pandas.Series.sum.html):

```
df['sum_3days'] = (df.groupby(['id'])['value']
                   .transform(lambda x: x.rolling(3, min_periods=1).sum()))
```

[output]

```
         date  id  value  sum_3days
0  2019-01-01   1      2          2
1  2019-01-01   2      3          3
2  2019-02-01   1      2          4
3  2019-02-01   2      5          8
4  2019-03-01   1      2          6
5  2019-03-01   2      1          9
6  2019-04-01   1      6         10
7  2019-05-01   1      3         11
8  2019-06-01   1      6         15
9  2019-06-01   2      8         14
10 2019-07-01   1      3         12
11 2019-07-01   2      2         11
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the function

```
Cumsum()
```

This webpage may be of help
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html

Comment: Yes, but the tricky part is to do a separate "cumsum" for every id, as well as setting the number of the days to be 3.